# What does MIT in Overwatch 2's scoreboard mean?

Tags: overwatch-2

Below is a screencap of Overwatch 2's scoreboard.
[image: scoreboard screencap, taken by me]

Each score is (assumingly) Elimination:Assist:Death, Damage, Healing. However, I don't get what does "MIT" mean here. For a moment I thought that's amount of damage prevented, but since Ana's got 137 of MIT score, I think it's wrong since she doesn't have any shield or immunity/immortality skills and such. It might be worth mentioning that I saw a Soldier 76 had a MIT score of 200+ yesterday (though I forgot to take screenshot), and he also doesn't have any shield or immunity/immortality skills.

So what does this MIT score mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MIT stands for [Damage Mitigated](https://overwatch.blizzard.com/en-us/news/patch-notes/beta/2022/06). Blizzard's patch notes specifically mention Ana's Nano Boost as one ability that contributes to this stat.

Comment: Nice to see the sources. Have you got any idea why soldier 76 had some of MIT score? As far as I remember he didn't change his hero, so... My guess is that his biotic field's healing also counts as MIT at some circumstances?

Comment: @Skye-AT As the other answer suggests, that's likely the damage negated by the healing effect. E.g. you take 50 damage from some source *while standing in the field*, that damage is recovered by the field, and voila, Soldier just mitigated 50 damage (and presumably this also adds to Soldier's healing done). On the other hand, entering the field and recovering 50 hp while not actively taking damage only counts toward Soldier's healing stat.

Comment: @user170231 Ahh that makes sense. Still makes me wonder why would Support like Lucio doesn't get MIT score in that kind of situation though (AFAIK he only receives MIT score by ulting his team). Or maybe I wasn't just checking. I'll look into it at some time.

Comment: I'm taking back what I said, after having played several QP games as Solder with no damage mitigation whatsoever... I'm not sure it's possible, but maybe there's just something I haven't tried.

Comment: Probably possible with killing some ulting hero such as Cassidy, Roadhog, etc... I'm unsure though, but I've played Soldier and managed to get some MIT score (unsure how though).

Answer (score 10):

It's the "Damage MITigated" column, which is, how much damage you have blocked/negated with your abilities.

It's therefore the defensive counterpart of the DMG ("damage inflicted") column.